# Array only adds duplicate values

Tags: c

When I print the contents of my array, it seems to override every element with the last command entered:

```
typedef struct
{
  int   argc;
  char* argv[10;
  char* myArray[80];
  size_t size;

} Command;
```

Inside main:

```
Command cmd;

cmd.myArray[cmd.size++] = buffer;
```

(Buffer being user input that I've checked with a printf to make sure it was the right thing being stored)

The function:

```
void myFunction(const Command* cmd)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < (cmd->size)-1; ++i)
    {
      printf("%s\n", cmd->myArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you allocating memory for char * pointer's before initializing it ?? And show what output you are getting. It would be easy to understand your questions

Answer (score 4):

You're setting every element of `myArray` to the same thing, `buffer`. You need to make copies of it to get distinct values:

```
char *temp = malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);
strcpy(temp, buffer);
cmd.myArray[cmd.size++] = temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

This assignment transfers the ownership of the buffer:

```
cmd.myArray[cmd.size++] = buffer;
```

In other words, from that assignment on you must not modify the buffer, because by doing so you would alter a previously stored command. In order for this to work properly, you need to either copy the buffer, or allocate a new one on each iteration. If you would like to use a copy, add a call to `strdup`:

```
cmd.myArray[cmd.size++] = strdup(buffer);
```

If you would prefer to allocate a new buffer, add

```
cmd.myArray[cmd.size++] = buffer;
buffer = malloc(BUF_SIZE); // buffer needs to be a `char *`
```

Answer (score 0):

If buffer is also a char*, you might need something like this instead:

```
cmd.myArray[cmd.size++] = buffer[cmd.size];
```